# ProgressDialog not showing while making HTTP request

Tags: android, progressdialog

I want to show ProgressDialog when http connection request.

there is request method.

```
protected Result request(String urlStr, String postData) {
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Loading...",true);
    Result result = new Result();
    String message = "";
    try {
        message = HttpRequest.postURL(urlStr, postData);
        result = new Result(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Failed to request data from " + urlStr + "\n" + e.getMessage());
    }
    dialog.dismiss();
    return result;
}
```

but when this method running. the ProgressDialog not showing.
how to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ProgressDialog not showing while performing a task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897205/progressdialog-not-showing-while-performing-a-task)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `dialog.show()`

> Start the dialog and display it on screen. The window is placed in the
>   application layer and opaque. Note that you should not override this
>   method to do initialization when the dialog is shown, instead
>   implement that in `onStart()`.

Also, what I do suggest is that you do this in `AsyncTask` class' `doInBackground()`.
In the `onPreExecute()`, display the `ProgressDialog` and in the `onPostExecute()` dismiss it.

Comment: buddy, i'm absolutely sure `ProgressDialog.show` will call `dialog.show()`, i been see it in source code

Comment: and i can't figure out how to return result if i do this in `AsyncTask`.i think this request must be synchronous

Comment: It depends. You can make `AsyncTask` as an inner class.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected Result request(String urlStr, String postData) {
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Loading...",true);
    Result result = new Result();
    String message = "";
    try {
        message = HttpRequest.postURL(urlStr, postData);
        result = new Result(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Failed to request data from " + urlStr + "\n" + e.getMessage());
    }
    dialog.show();
    return result;
}
```

don't forget to call dialog.dismiss(); with a button

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for the progress dialog not showing, but in your case, i guess it's because you passing the wrong `Context` to show the `ProgessDialog`, please check your `Activity` context. Make sure you use proper `Context`for that or just change it to `ApplicationContext`

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Loading...",true);
```

Check this line, especially the `activity`. Hope this helps.