# ProgressDialog cannot show when put ProgressDialog.dismiss method

Tags: java, android, android-layout, progressdialog

`ProgressDialog` cannot show when i add `progressDialog.dismiss()` method on my code

I also try to add `Thread.sleep()` so that it execution will sleep for some time which can show `progressdialog` for some time but this will also not work.

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class Extraction {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public Extraction(List<ResolveInfo> apps, String publicSourceDir, String apkname, Context context) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Extracting");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();
        BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;
        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(publicSourceDir);
            File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Extracted APK");

            if (!file1.exists())
                file1.mkdirs();

            file1 = new File(file1.getPath() + "/" + apkname + ".apk");
            if (!file1.exists())
                file1.createNewFile();


            bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file1));

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = bufferedInputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                bufferedOutputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(context, "Apk Extracted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            bufferedInputStream.close();
            bufferedOutputStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                bufferedInputStream.close();
                bufferedOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are dismissing the progressDialog and you want it to show? Don't dismiss it then..

Comment: i think he need to show it and then dismiss it after completion of the file manipulation

Answer (score 1):

your need to put your long running work in a separate Thread or asyncTask

Because the UI is only updated at the end when your long running code is completed and then the show/dismiss is already called. thats why you only see the final result: a dismissed dialog

see the example (quoted from here:
[Android: ProgressDialog doesn't show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798443/android-progressdialog-doesnt-show) ):

> Do something like:
>
> ```
> public void doBackup(View view) throws IOException{
>     final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
>     pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
>     pd.setMessage("Running backup. Do not unplug drive");
>     pd.setIndeterminate(true);
>     pd.setCancelable(false);
>     pd.show();
>     Thread mThread = new Thread() {
>         @Override
>       public void run() {
>             File source = new File("/mnt/extSdCard/DirectEnquiries"); 
>             File dest = new File("/mnt/UsbDriveA/Backup");
>             copyDirectory(source, dest);
>             pd.dismiss();
>         }
>     };
>     mThread.start();
> }
> ```

and also here:
[ProgressDialog not showing while performing a task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897205/progressdialog-not-showing-while-performing-a-task)